# Sherman-Morrison Formula to determine the inverse of matrix

Tags: matrices, analysis, inverse, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

$$
A= \pmatrix{
1 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1}
$$

How would we compute the inverse of A using the Sherman-Morrison Formula?

I believe the answer will be below, but I like to know the steps, please.
$$
A^{-1}=\pmatrix{
1 & -2 & 4 & -8 \\
0 & 1 & -2 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
}
$$

Comment: hi Micheal. Why do you believe the answer to be what you have shown? Also, you should use our standard typesetting system, MathJax. I paste the link for you here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164/

Comment: I found the inverse of this matrix in Matlab

Answer (score 2):

Sherman-Morrison formula is about rank-one updates. Your $A$ is not a rank-one update of a matrix whose determinant and inverse are easy to compute (unless you are familiar with *circulant matrices*). It is a bad idea to apply Sherman-Morrison formula here.

A simpler idea is to exploit the fact that $A=I+2J$ where $J$ is a *nilpotent matrix*. Since $J^4=0$. We have $I-(2J)^4=I$. So, from the factorisation $1-x^4=(1+x)(1-x+x^2-x^3)$, we obtain
$$
(I+2J)\left[I-(2J)+(2J)^2-(2J)^3\right]=I-(2J)^4=I.
$$
Therefore $A^{-1}=(I+2J)^{-1}=I-(2J)+(2J)^2-(2J)^3$.